# JSON Date issues - changing between request and actual date received by model

Tags: json, datetime, user-interface, deployment

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. We've got a user interface that sends JSON requests to a model which then sends back a JSON response containing prices.

This is the date being sent in the request JSON that our UI developers have provided:
"TransactionEffectiveDate": "2023-04-07T00:00:00+01:00",

This is what I believe is actually being received by the model:
"TransactionEffectiveDate": "2023-04-06T23:00:00",

An error was showing in the UI so I was provided with the JSON messages for that quote. I ran the request through the model offline just like I normally would but the output produced offline doesn't match the response reported by the UI developers.

The response JSON provided by the UI team shows a different date to the request which would suggest that the model has changed it but there doesn't seem to be any reason for it to do that and we've never seen this issue before.

The only way that I can reproduce the error offline is by manually changing the date in the request to match the response JSON which suggests to me that the request message is being distorted somewhere between being recorded in the UI and actually reaching the model.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Or can you think of anything that might cause it to happen?